# OpenCV measure rectangular image size

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an app that finds an object in a frame and uses `warpPerspective` to correct the image to be square. In the course of doing so you specify an output image size. However, I want to know how to do so without harming its apparent size. How can I unwarp the 4-corners of the image without changing the size of the image? I don't need the image itself, I just want to measure its height and width in pixels within the original image.

#### Get a transform matrix that will square up the corners.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> transformedPoints;
cv::Mat M = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(points, objectCorners);
cv::perspectiveTransform(points, transformedPoints, M);
```

This will square up the image, but in terms of the `objectCorners` coordinate system. Which is -0.5f to 0.5f not the original image plane.

#### BoundingRect almost does what I want.

```
cv::Rect boundingRectangle = cv::boundingRect(points);
```

But as the [documentation states](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect)

> The function calculates and returns the minimal up-right bounding rectangle for the specified point set.

And what I want is the bounding rectangle after it has been squared-up, not without squaring it up.

Comment: You want the size of the warped image? create points for the 4 corners of the image; warp those points (e.g. multiply homogeneous version of those points with your homography and dehomogenize); compute boundingRect of those transformed corner points. voila

Comment: Can you add this as an answer? Also, I'm unfamiliar with homography. Could you provide some code? If you at least add it as an answer I'll add the code when I have it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Minimum bounding rect of the points

```
cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));
```

As the [minAreaRect reference](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect) on OpenCV's website states

> Finds a rotated rectangle of the minimum area enclosing the input 2D point set.

You can call `box.size` and get the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding to your post, here is something which should help you. 
[OpenCV perspective transform example](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/05/05/building-pokedex-python-opencv-perspective-warping-step-5-6/).

Update if it still doesn't help you out in finding the height and width within the image

Comment: I have seen this, but his calculation is done without taking into account the warping the image. It would work OK, but I'm looking for a way to make the object square-up before determining the rectangle.